How to view Ep Reward mean when using TensorBoard with stable Baselines 3
I am not seeing ep_rwd_mean when running tensorboard.
I can only see
train/fps
train/approx_kl
train/clip_fraction
train/clip_range
train/entropy_loss
train/explained_variance
train/learning_rate
train/loss
train/policy_gradient_loss
train/value_loss

Below is my learn() function
According to this post, Understanding the tensorboard plots on a stable-baseline3's PPO    ep_rwd_mean is shown per 100 episodes.
If my simulation has 1000 time steps per episode, but less than 100 episodes, is this the reason it is not showing?
Can I make it show the reward per episode?
def learn():
    models_dir = "models/square/"
    log_dir = "logs/square/"

    if not os.path.exists(models_dir):
        os.makedirs(models_dir)

    if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
        os.makedirs(log_dir)

    env = SquareGameEnv()
    check_env(env)
    env.reset()

    model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_dir)

    NUM_ACTIONS = num_squares*4  # Number of actions to send in each training step
    STEPS_PER_EPISODE = 1000

    episodes = 1000
    for i in range(episodes):
        episode_reward = 0
        # Accumulate rewards over multiple steps
        for _ in range(STEPS_PER_EPISODE):
            obs = env.reset()

            total_rewards = []
            # Sample multiple actions
            actions = [model.predict(obs)[0] for _ in range(NUM_ACTIONS)]
            
            obs, reward, done, _ = env.step(actions)
            episode_reward += reward
            env.render(mode='human')
            if done:
                break

        # Update the model after each episode
        model.learn(total_timesteps=STEPS_PER_EPISODE * NUM_ACTIONS, reset_num_timesteps=False)

        # Save the model after each episode
        model.save(f"{models_dir}/{i + 1}")

        print("Episode:", i + 1, "Total Reward:", episode_reward)


I recently came into the same problem and I solved it by properly setting the argument stats_window_size of the constructor of PPO model class (by default set at 100). In accordance with the documentation (here), it defines the

window size for the rollout logging, specifying the number of episodes to average the reported success rate, mean episode length, and mean reward over.

